# c# webcrawling beginner using visual studio having questions about adding link

Tags: c#, linq, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

So here is what I have done for scraping http://stock.hankyung.com/news/app/newslist.php?cid=01

I have attached my files because some how it won't ctrl+v in this website

As you can see this will only scrape the first page of the news, now I want to do how to scrape the news from page 1 to the end (43199) but I am not sure where to start I am very beginner and I started c# like few weeks ago but I am very interested in coding and I want to learn from master of c#. Sorry for my bad English.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZDv7.png)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your current page in the pager is a span not a link so here's what I'd do.
First find the pager at the bottom:

```
public bool GoToNextPage()
{

IWebElement pager = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("descendant::div[@class='paging']"));

//Then find the current page:
List<IWebElement> nextPage = pager.FindElements(By.Xpath("descendant::span\following-sibling::a")).ToList();
if(nextPage.Count > 0)
{
nextPage.First().Click();
return true;
}
else{
//you're at the end of the pages
return false;
}
}
```

then I'd structure the program like so:

```
bool hasNextPage = true;
while(hasNextPage)
{
//your existing scrape functionality here
hasNextPage = GoToNextPage();
}
```

Comment: if people are downvoting could you at least comment why?

Comment: problem is when you hit nextpage it doesn't go 1->2->3->4 it goes 1->11->21->31

Comment: that's why you use the span to find where you're at. If you're on page 1, the span is page 1 so the next page is the following link (the page 2 link). If you're on page 10, the span is page 10, so the following link is the arrow. Clicking the arrow takes you to page 11, now the span is 11, so the next link is 12.